# How can I switch my attack button on League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am using a MacBook Pro to play League of Legends. As you may or may not know, the MacBooks **do not** feature two mouse buttons, but instead a central one. I want to know if I can switch my attack trigger from a click to a key. Is this possible

Comment: have you checked the key bindings in the options menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "attack button."

League of Legends has four commands relevant to attack: Player Move Click, Player Attack Move Click, Player Attack Only Click, and Player Attack Move. All four bindings can be found in Hotkeys → Additional Hotkeys → Player Movement and can be rebound as you like. Note that although the commands ending in Click are bound to mouse buttons by default, they may be rebound to keys without change in functionality.

[image]

I'll give a short description of each with their Windows bindings.

Player Move Click (default <kbd>RMB</kbd>): This is the main moving key, bound by default to the right mouse button. This will move you to the location under your mouse cursor, unless you click on an enemy, in which case it will move you into range of them and then attack them. This results in a green targeting indicator (blue in colour-blind mode).

Player Attack Move Click (default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>): Like PMC, this will move you to the location under your cursor. However, as soon as an enemy (note: does not include neutral monsters, aggroed or not) comes within auto-attack range, your champion will begin attacking it. This results in a red targeting indicator (orange in colour-blind mode).

Player Attack Only Click (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>): Unlike PMC and PAMC, this will not move you to a location. You must have your cursor over an enemy or neutral monster when pressing this. Upon doing so, your champion will move into auto-attack range and begin attacking. No targeting indicator is shown.

Player Attack Move (default <kbd>A</kbd>): This changes your cursor to show a red diamond cursor icon (yellow in colour-blind mode). After you click (with <kbd>LMB</kbd> in Windows), it acts exactly like PAMC, including displaying the targeting indicator.

[image]

The reference image above shows the targeting indicators and the cursors. In order from left to right, they are PMC, PMC (colour-blind), PAMC, PAMC (colour-blind), PAM, and PAM (colour-blind). The first four are animated indicators shown on the ground, and the last two are cursor replacements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on what to change. I have successfully remapped all four buttons and I am now playing without hindrance.

Comment: @YoungCoder2297 I'm glad I could help! Please consider marking this answer as accepted. Thanks! :)